# Print Overview widget as part of map

Tags: printing, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am using ArcGIS viewer for Flex 2.4. I am trying to get the overview map to print as part of the map using the print widget. In my customized print widget, the user has the facility to opt for overview map. For this, I intend to open the overview map widget from Print widget. Since it is a UI widget and does not seem to entertain widget id, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I did this project work:
 http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6809086326ea4c76bf026a32bb9dd698

I think it would be possible to add your functionality.