# Print overview map widget

Tags: printing, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

I am using ArcGIS viewer for flex v3.6 to create a web map. Can someone tell me if it is possible to print the overview map widget as part of your map? 
P/s: I know someone asked this question 2 years ago but there wasn't an answer for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print Overview widget as part of map](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20868/print-overview-widget-as-part-of-map)

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open, since the answer on the other question doesn't solve this or that question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to print the overview map together with the map because the default print service doesn't support that functionality.
http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/create-web-apps/windows/printing-in-web-applications.htm

However, it might be possible if you set up your own printing server using ArcGIS Server.
http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/create-web-apps/windows/advanced-printing-for-web-maps.htm